# Change popover color/class based on parents value criteria

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm bringing data from back end server and creating divs to represent data. I'm adding Boostrap's popover and everything looks good. However, I want to change the popover color depending on the a variable if is greater than 20. 
for example.

```
  //Ajax from Server:
    //loop thru data
    for (var i in c) {
      var myid =   c[i][0]
      var myTime = c[i][1]
      $("#holdcontainer").append('<div id="' + myid+ '" data-toggle="popover"  data-container="body"  data-placement="top"  title="test1" data-content=" ' + myid + '  Time: ' + myTime + '" >' +myTime  + '</div>'

      if (myTime > 30) {
        //trying this but not working. 
        $("#" +myid + " .popover-title").css({ "background": "red", "color": "white" });
      }
    } //end loop

    //initiate popover
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
```

Comment: And...does that not work? Where does it fail? What goes wrong? What errors are there? What's your (relevant) HTML?

Comment: It does not change the color. I just get the gray/default popover color. no console error. so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selector $("#" +myid + " .popover-title") not work because .popover-title is not part of "#" +myid.

maybe the solution is to add shown event:

UPDATE (event is outside the loop )

```
function start()
{
    for (var i in c) {

        var myid =   c[i][0]
        var myTime = c[i][1]

        $("#holdcontainer").append('<div id="' + myid+ '" data-toggle="popover"  data-container="body"  data-placement="top"  title="test1" data-content=" ' + myid + '  Time: ' + myTime + '" >' +myTime  + '</div>');

        if(myTime>30)     $("#" +myid).attr('data-new-class','newTitle');
    }

     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({             
            trigger: "hover"             
        }).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
           var newClass=$(this).attr('data-new-class');        

            if (typeof newClass !== "undefined")                
                $(".popover-title:visible").addClass(newClass)

        });

}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lxmz9xy/3/)

Comment: Very smart. I'm on mobile but is the event inside the loop or after the loop? If inside the loop would it cause performance issues for about 7k rows?  Thanks!

Comment: I made the changes. Please look above

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that myTime is being interpreted as a string, instead of a number?

Try this:

```
var myTime = Number(c[i][1]);
```

It would be easier to try if you set up a JSFiddle.